# Can Idris infer indices in types of top-level constants?

Tags: type-inference, agda, idris

For example, Agda allows me to write this:

```
open import Data.Vec
open import Data.Nat

myVec : Vec ℕ _
myVec = 0 ∷ 1 ∷ 2 ∷ 3 ∷ []
```

and `myVec` will have type `Vec ℕ 4` as expected.

But if I try the same in Idris:

```
import Data.Vect

myVec : Vect _ Nat
myVec = [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

I get an error message from the typechecker:

```
 When checking right hand side of myVec with expected type
         Vect len Nat

 Type mismatch between
         Vect 4 Nat (Type of [0, 1, 2, 3])
 and
         Vect len Nat (Expected type)

 Specifically:
         Type mismatch between
                 4
         and
                 len
```

Is there a way to define `myVec` in Idris without manually specifying the index of the `Vect`?

Comment: If I add a hole in place of `_` like so: `myVec : Vect ?len Nat; myVec = [0, 1, 2, 3]`, then Idris is able solve the hole `?len` (`C-c C-a` in Emacs). This is probably not what you want, though.

Comment: IIRC, Idris treats `_` at the type level as a fresh universally quantified variable. I.e. your expression elaborates to something like `myVec : forall len. Vect len Nat`.

Answer (score 2):

Per the comments, top-level holes in Idris was universally quantified, instead of being filled via term inference.

I believe (but, ultimately someone from the development team would have to confirm / deny) that this was done partially to encourage explicit types, and thus type-directed development, and partially to have a nice syntax for don't-care values in interface implementations like:

```
Uninhabited v => Uninhabited (_, v) where
    uninhabited (_, void) = uninhabited void
```

This don't-care use of the underscore is adopted from it's use in patterns, rather than it's use in expressions.

---

For something like this (it's not exactly what you want, but it is robust against changes to the constant), you can use an explicit existential:

```
fst : DPair t _ -> t
fst (x ** _) = x

snd : (s : DPair _ p) -> p (fst s)
snd (_ ** prf) = prf

myVecEx : (n ** Vect n Nat)
myVecEx = (_ ** [0, 1, 2, 3])

myVec : Vect (fst myVecEx) Nat
myVec = snd myVecEx
```

`fst` and `snd` might be in the standard library under different names, but I didn't find then in a quick search.

EDIT: An upvote recently drew this answer to my attention again.  If you are using Idris 2, I believe you can use a `?` instead of a `_` at the top level to have it filled in my idris.  `_` at the top level, is an erased, implicit, unnamed parameter, still.  https://idris2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/implementation/overview.html#additional-type-inference

Comment: That's all fine & dandy, but is there a way (unrelated to the `_` syntax) to let Idris infer my indices?

Comment: Explicit existentials, maybe? Or maybe use a `?hole` and proof-search it once your constants are fixed?

Comment: (Added an example of using an existential.)